# Resize app windows beyond display

Tags: gratis, osx

I'm looking for some software that can let me resize windows to be bigger than actual screen size. Something similar to [Infinite Screen](http://ynea.futureware.at/cgi-bin/infinite_screen.pl).

I would like this software to be free and available on OSX.